# Spring multiple jsp included in the same form gives error on Ajax callback

Tags: java, ajax, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

Hy I have a jsp with cv form with his fields:

```
<form:form commandName="cv" action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/site/my-account/cv/save" id="cv-template-form" method="POST">
<h3><spring:message code="view.candidates.form.workExperience" /></h3>
    <div id="workExperienceDiv">
        <jsp:include page="/WEB-INF/views/site/commons/cv/workExperience.jsp"/> 
    </div>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="AjaxUtils.submitAttribute('${pageContext.request.contextPath}/site/my-account/cv/save/workExperience','workExperienceDiv');" class="btn btn-large btn-block btn-lightgray">
        <spring:message code="button.labe.add.more"/>
    </a>
<h3><spring:message code="view.candidates.form.education" /></h3>
    <div id="educationDiv">
        <jsp:include page="/WEB-INF/views/site/commons/cv/education.jsp"/>  
    </div>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="AjaxUtils.submitAttribute('${pageContext.request.contextPath}/site/my-account/cv/save/education','educationDiv');" class="btn btn-large btn-block btn-lightgray">
        <spring:message code="button.labe.add.more"/>
    </a>
```

Work experience jsp:

```
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="spring"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>

    <c:forEach var="workExperience" items="${cv.workExperiences}" >
        <div class="row">
            <label class="col-md-4"><spring:message code="view.candidates.form.workExperience.employer" /></label>
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <input value="${workExperience.employer}" id="employer" class="text block"/>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <label class="col-md-4"><spring:message code="view.candidates.form.workExperience.period" /></label>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="datepicker">
                    <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
                    <input value="${workExperience.dateFrom}" class="text block date"/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="datepicker">
                    <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
                    <input value="${workExperience.dateTo}" class="text date block"/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <label class="col-md-4"><spring:message code="view.candidates.form.workExperience.position" /></label>
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <input value="${workExperience.position}" id="position" type="text" class="text block"/>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <label class="col-md-4"><spring:message code="view.candidates.form.workExperience.activities" /></label>
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <textarea class="textarea block">${workExperience.position}</textarea>
            </div>
        </div>  

        <div class="row">
            <a class="editor_remove" href="#" onclick="AjaxUtils.submitAttribute('${pageContext.request.contextPath}/site/my-account/cv/delete/workExperience/${workExperience.tempId}');">
                <i class="fa fa-times"></i>Remove
            </a>
        </div>
    </c:forEach>

    <div class="row">
        <label class="col-md-4"><spring:message code="view.candidates.form.workExperience.employer" /></label>
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <form:errors id="employerError" path="workExperience.employer" cssClass="error"/>
            <form:input path="workExperience.employer" id="employer" class="text block" cssErrorClass="text block error"/>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <label class="col-md-4"><spring:message code="view.candidates.form.workExperience.period"/></label>
        <div class="col-md-4">
        <form:errors path="workExperience.dateFrom" cssClass="error"/>
            <div class="datepicker">
                <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
                <form:input path="workExperience.dateFrom" cssClass="text block date" cssErrorClass="text block date error" placeholder="From"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="datepicker">
                <form:errors path="workExperience.dateTo" cssClass="error"/>
                <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
                <form:input path="workExperience.dateTo" cssClass="text date block" cssErrorClass="text date block error" placeholder="To"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <label class="col-md-4"><spring:message code="view.candidates.form.workExperience.position" /></label>
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <form:errors path="workExperience.position" cssClass="error"/>
            <form:input path="workExperience.position" id="position" type="text" class="text block" cssErrorClass="text block error"/>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <label class="col-md-4"><spring:message code="view.candidates.form.workExperience.activities" /></label>
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <form:errors path="workExperience.activities" cssClass="error"/>
            <form:textarea path="workExperience.activities" cssClass="textarea block" cssErrorClass="textarea block error"/>
        </div>
    </div>
```

ajax function:

```
submitAttribute: function (url1,div){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: url1,
            data: $('#cv-template-form').serialize(),
            cache: false,
            success: function(data) {
                $('#'+div).html(data);
                Utils.Pikaday.init("input.date");
            }
        }); 
    },
```

And education look like the workExperience jsp. Theoreticly I want to fill workExperience fields send it with ajax and put it in a workExperienceList and send back the list and a new workExperience. The problem is in ajax callback gives me an error cause he did not recognize the workExperience in workExperience.jsp. 
This is the error:

```
 SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [spring-mvc-dispatcher] in context with path [/] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.apache.tiles.request.render.CannotRenderException: ServletException including path '/WEB-INF/views/site/commons/cv/workExperience.jsp'.] with root cause
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'workExperience' available as request attribute
```

If i put a new form with commandName="cv" in workExperience.jsp it works fine but if I put in education that form to then he did not recognize first time, in java it comes null. I don`t want to put commandName="workExperience" in workExperience.jsp because if I want to save the big cv then he will not put the workExperience.jsp fields in cv object. Any solution?

Comment: Avoid spring form tags. Use HTML tags and EL.

Comment: I need spring tags, I can`t avoid it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved it, its not so good but it is working fine I add a c:if if it is loaded first time with the big form then show it without workExperience form if it is returned from java the jsp page then show with workExperience form. Variable ajax is true just when the workExperience jsp page is returned from java. Now this is my workExperience form:

```
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="spring"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>

<c:set var="index" value="0"/>
<c:if test="${ajax == true}">

    <form:form commandName="cv">
        <c:forEach var="workExperience" items="${cv.workExperiences}" >
            <div class="row">
                <label class="col-md-4"><spring:message code="view.candidates.form.workExperience.employer" /></label>
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    <form:errors id="employerError" path="workExperiences[${index}].employer" cssClass="error"/>
                    <form:input path="workExperiences[${index}].employer" id="employer" class="text block" cssErrorClass="text block error"/>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <label class="col-md-4"><spring:message code="view.candidates.form.workExperience.period"/></label>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                <form:errors path="workExperiences[${index}].dateFrom" cssClass="error"/>
                    <div class="datepicker">
                        <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
                        <form:input path="workExperiences[${index}].dateFrom" cssClass="text block date" cssErrorClass="text block date error" placeholder="From"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="datepicker">
                        <form:errors path="workExperiences[${index}].dateTo" cssClass="error"/>
                        <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
                        <form:input path="workExperiences[${index}].dateTo" cssClass="text date block" cssErrorClass="text date block error" placeholder="To"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <label class="col-md-4"><spring:message code="view.candidates.form.workExperience.position" /></label>
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    <form:errors path="workExperiences[${index}].position" cssClass="error"/>
                    <form:input path="workExperiences[${index}].position" id="position" type="text" class="text block" cssErrorClass="text block error"/>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <label class="col-md-4"><spring:message code="view.candidates.form.workExperience.activities" /></label>
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    <form:errors path="workExperiences[${index}].activities" cssClass="error"/>
                    <form:textarea path="workExperiences[${index}].activities" cssClass="textarea block" cssErrorClass="textarea block error"/>
                </div>
            </div>

            <c:if test="${index < cv.workExperiences.size()-1 || cv.workExperiences[index].id != null}">
                <a class="editor_remove" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="AjaxUtils.submitAttribute('${pageContext.request.contextPath}/site/my-account/cv/delete/workExperience/${index}','workExperienceDiv');">
                    <i class="fa fa-times"></i><spring:message code="button.label.remove"/>
                </a>
            </c:if>
            <c:set var="index" value="${index+1}"/>
        </c:forEach>
    </form:form>
</c:if>

<c:if test="${ajax != true}">

    <c:forEach var="workExperience" items="${cv.workExperiences}" >
        <div class="row">
            <label class="col-md-4"><spring:message code="view.candidates.form.workExperience.employer" /></label>
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <form:errors id="employerError" path="workExperiences[${index}].employer" cssClass="error"/>
                <form:input path="workExperiences[${index}].employer" id="employer" class="text block" cssErrorClass="text block error"/>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <label class="col-md-4"><spring:message code="view.candidates.form.workExperience.period"/></label>
            <div class="col-md-4">
            <form:errors path="workExperiences[${index}].dateFrom" cssClass="error"/>
                <div class="datepicker">
                    <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
                    <form:input path="workExperiences[${index}].dateFrom" cssClass="text block date" cssErrorClass="text block date error" placeholder="From"/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="datepicker">
                    <form:errors path="workExperiences[${index}].dateTo" cssClass="error"/>
                    <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
                    <form:input path="workExperiences[${index}].dateTo" cssClass="text date block" cssErrorClass="text date block error" placeholder="To"/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <label class="col-md-4"><spring:message code="view.candidates.form.workExperience.position" /></label>
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <form:errors path="workExperiences[${index}].position" cssClass="error"/>
                <form:input path="workExperiences[${index}].position" id="position" type="text" class="text block" cssErrorClass="text block error"/>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <label class="col-md-4"><spring:message code="view.candidates.form.workExperience.activities" /></label>
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <form:errors path="workExperiences[${index}].activities" cssClass="error"/>
                <form:textarea path="workExperiences[${index}].activities" cssClass="textarea block" cssErrorClass="textarea block error"/>
            </div>
        </div>

        <c:if test="${index < cv.workExperiences.size()-1 || cv.workExperiences[index].id != null}">
            <a class="editor_remove" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="AjaxUtils.submitAttribute('${pageContext.request.contextPath}/site/my-account/cv/delete/workExperience/${index}','workExperienceDiv');">
                <i class="fa fa-times"></i><spring:message code="button.label.remove"/>
            </a>
        </c:if>
        <c:set var="index" value="${index+1}"/>
    </c:forEach>
</c:if>
```